# Creating a loop from cell text and deleting sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to stackoverflow, and programming in general, so please give me a little slack for 
what I'm guessing is an obvious question.

I've started writing macros in excel the last couple of months, and I think it should be possible to loop what I'm working on, but I'm not entirely sure how to actually make it happen.

I'm trying to do two things:

1. I want to pull the text from a cell, which will also be the name of the sheet.
2. I want to look and delete the sheets with a zero value.

This is what I have right now:

```vb
If Range("L1").Value = 0 Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("EA4A").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Else: Sheets("Sheet3").Select
```

The first 3 lines check the pulled data and delete the sheet (ideally). I want the EA4A to be pulled from cell C1. I also have this copied and pasted from L1 to L72, but that could change fairly regularly. The Sheet names are listed down column C, so I thought there is probably a way to loop the names, check the value = 0, and delete the zeros.

Again, I just started a couple months ago so if this is just plain awful I'm willing to learn whatever I can to improve. I thought seeing this in action might help at this point, as I've spend days on google trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheetname
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    With ws
        For i = 1 To 72
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            If .Range("L" & i).Value = 0 Then _
            Sheets(.Range("C" & i).Value).Delete

            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Next i
    End With

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is this that u need but i made below one code to find the names and put it in the first column and an other code to delete the sheets with value 0 in the second column based on the order found in the first code and not based on the name of the sheet.

I hope it helps.

```
'====Code 01===
Sub FindNames()

Dim i As String
Dim Ro As Integer

Range("A:B").ClearContents
i = ActiveSheet.Name
Ro = 1
    For Each Sh In Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Cells(Ro, 1).Value = Sh.Name
        Ro = Ro + 1
    Next Sh
End Sub

'====Code 02===
Sub DeleteSh()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim i As String
Dim Ro As Integer

i = ActiveSheet.Name
Ro = 1
    For Each Sh In Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
        If Cells(Ro, 2).Value = 0 Then Sh.Delete
        Ro = Ro + 1
    Next Sh

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Setting .DisplayAlerts = False at the very beginning of the code is a bad idea. It will suppress all the prompts :) Just my two cents...